# Get email from user at checkout success page

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, order-success-page

I am overriding the checkout success page, `Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml` and I want to let the user to know that a confirmation e-mail is send to his/her e-mail address.

Is there any way to show the e-mail address, that the user has filled in the checkout page? I have tried searching for methods like `getEmail` but could not find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overwrite **Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success**

**Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Onepage\Success" />
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Block/Onepage/Success.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    public function getEmail()
    {
        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        return $order->getCustomerEmail();
    }
}
```

Now inside your **success.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getEmail(); ?>
```

Make sure your template is define inside **checkout_onepage_success.xml** following way:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success" template="Magento_Checkout::success.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

That means **Magento_Checkout** before **success.phtml** in template attribute.

Clear cache.

Comment: If I were to reproduce this in `app/` (instead of `vendor/`), would this be done in `app/code` or could I achieve this in my child theme under `app/design/<theme>/<child_theme>`?

Comment: 'app/code/Vendor/Module' should be ok